# Third party MMS stack using SIP

Tags: iphone, ios, sip, mms, pjsip

Is there any third party stack available for MMS using SIP. or is there any SIP stack available which support MMS.

we have to integrate MMS facility in our VOIP client in iPhone. It seems that we have to use some third party MMS stack to do this. So i am searching any third part MMS stack.

Please forgive me if the terminology is not correct.

Thanks